# Extract Data from XAML using Python

Tags: python, xml, xaml, elementtree, treenode

I am very new to XAMLs and want to know the way to extract the data from a XAML file using Python(I am aware of the basic use of XML module).
For example one of the line is:

```
<Variable x:TypeArguments="sd:DataTable" Name="Yoko_Hara" />
```

From the above line, I want to extract the name of this variable.

I tried the following code and get empty output:

```
> from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
> 
> data = ET.parse("inputfile/main.xaml")     
> root = data.getroot() 
> for elem in root.iter('Variable'):
>     print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to access it using attribute i.e Name

use

```
print(elem.attrib['Name'])
```

instead of

```
print(elem.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you're trying to get the text, which is the value between the start and end tags. Given the following:

```xml
<Variable Name="somename">Text</Variable>
```

`elem.text` produces "Text".

The one you actually need is the Attribute part, which is accessible like so:

```py
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

data = ET.parse("inputfile/main.xaml")     
root = data.getroot() 
for elem in root.iter('Variable'):
     print(elem.attrib['Name'])
```